# redirect a domain to a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain

I want to build a site with this domain structure and flexiblily.

My main advertising site will be at `www.website.com`

Customers will log into their admin portal at `admin.website.com`

The world will have access to each customer's public site at `customer-name.website.com`

That part is straight forward and I can handle it, but I also want to do the following:

I want to give the customer the option to buy a domain name, from an outside seller, and somehow link it to their public site.  So they can have a regular domain name of their choice instead of having people go to a subdomain address like `customer-site.website.com`

The customer can either buy a domain or use one they already own and is hosted at godaddy and make it redirect to their public site: `www.customersite.com` redirects to `customer-name.website.com`

I won't have access to the customers domain name, www.customersite.com, which will be hosted by godaddy.  My site, `www.website.com` is not hosted by godaddy and the customer's site, `customer-site.website.com` isn't either.  How can this be done in general, I'm not looking for specific directions with godaddy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this up with a CNAME record. `www.customersite.com` would be a CNAME that points at `customer-name.website.com`, which the customer would set up at their domain registrar (godaddy, namecheap, gandi, etc).

One caveat with CNAMEs is that they should only be applied to subdomains like `www`. Applying them to the root `customersite.com` leads to really bad things, so they should use their registrar's DNS settings to redirect `customersite.com` to `www.customersite.com`.